# How to get a Date from a JSON object

Tags: java, json, date, object, getdate

I have a JSON object, which have one field that is a birthdate:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
User user = new User();
user.setuserID(obj.getString("userID"));
user.setisMale(obj.getBoolean("isMale"));
user.setEmail(obj.getString("email"));
// user.setBirthdate(obj.getDate("birthdate"));
user.setLastName(obj.getString("lastName"));
user.setFirstName(obj.getString("firstName"));
```

But the method `getDate()` does not exist in JSONObject.
How can I set the Birthdate in my User object?

Comment: How is your date represented in the JSON response? I guess a String? Show the JSON.

Comment: It's like: "birthdate":"2012-08-01"

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You may do like below,

```
String dateStr = obj.getString("birthdate");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date birthDate = sdf.parse(dateStr);
//then
user.setBirthdate(birthDate);
```

Hope to help you :)

Comment: It resulted, but it is printing `Wed Aug 01 00:00:00 BST 2012`, even my format is `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: your result is normal, because the format partten is "yyyy-MM-dd", please use "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" to get hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: @Bob.Z I am getting date string like this "2015-12-25 00:00:00" i want to format like this "2015-12-25 00:00:00 UTC". which format should i write in the `SimpleDateFormat("?")`.

Comment: I would prefer the onliner new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").parse(dateStr)

Answer (score 4):

In general, a date is passed as milliseconds or as a formatted string. So depending upon your json you can use either use `new Date(json.getLong(milliseconds))` or if date is in string

```
String birthdate = json.getString(date);//"2013-03-26"
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: It resulted, but it is printing `Wed Aug 01 00:00:00 BST 2012`, even my format is `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")`