# JSONObject["user_birthday"] not a string

Tags: java, json, org.json

Sorry for the repeated problem but I didn't found the answer on google.
I am trying to parse json to an object of setter/getter class.

```
public ArrayList<User> getArrayList(StringBuffer jsonReceived){
    ArrayList<User> userArrayList = new ArrayList<User>();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonReceived.toString());
    JSONArray userTable = json.getJSONArray("user");
    for (int i = 0; i < userTable.length(); i++) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(userTable.getJSONObject(i).getInt("user_id"));
        user.setLastName(userTable.getJSONObject(i).getString("user_last_name"));
        user.setFirstName(userTable.getJSONObject(i).getString("user_first_name"));
        user.setEmail(userTable.getJSONObject(i).getString("user_email"));
        System.out.println(userTable.getJSONObject(i).getString("user_birthday"));
        String dateStr = userTable.getJSONObject(i).getString("user_birthday");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        try {
            Date birthDate = sdf.parse(dateStr);
            user.setBirthday(birthDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        user.setCountry(userTable.getJSONObject(i).getString("user_country"));
        user.setCity(userTable.getJSONObject(i).getString("user_city"));
        userArrayList.add(user);
    }
    System.out.println("la list d'utilisateurs : "+userTable.toString());
    System.out.println("ArrayList : "+userArrayList.toString());
    return userArrayList;
}
```

Here mon json string user :

```
{
"tag": "getUsers",
"success": 1,
"error": 0,
"user": [
    {
        "user_id": "1",
        "user_last_name": "Alain",
        "user_first_name": "Ron",
        "user_birthday": "2014-02-01",
        "user_email": "alain@ron.fr",
        "user_country": "",
        "user_city": ""
    },
    {
        "user_id": "2",
        "user_last_name": "Rodrigues",
        "user_first_name": "Richard",
        "user_birthday": null,
        "user_email": "richard@r.fr",
        "user_country": null,
        "user_city": null
    }
]}
```

and my error log is :

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["user_birthday"] not a string.
>       at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:661)
>       at fr.moveo.applicationlourde.services.AbstractMethods.getArrayList(AbstractMethods.java:50)
>       at fr.moveo.applicationlourde.Views.frames.WindowConnexion.actionPerformed(WindowConnexion.java:75)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)

I have tried all the methods I found in the first and the second page of google but it didn't work....

Comment: seem to remember something like this off the top of my head, is there a getOptString method that you could try instead?

Comment: According to this answer, you can test with .has(string) and .isNull(string): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585492/how-to-test-if-a-jsonobject-is-null-or-doesnt-exist

Comment: does it run through if you remove the birthday? or is there a bigger issue?

Comment: also this link provides a method for getting a date from JSON object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761101/how-to-get-a-date-from-a-json-object

Comment: Does that happen on the first user or on the second where the birthday is null?

Comment: @DerekKurth I already tried this solution but it didn't work

Comment: @JoeLloyd yes it work without the birthday but the country have the same problem

Comment: @RealSkeptic it happen on the firstUser

Comment: @JoeLloyd I apply this method but the problem occur before it.

Comment: Can you print the `userTable.getJSONObject(i)` itself (whole object) and see if you see the birthday etc. in there?

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes, I can see the birthday ("user_birthday": "2014-02-01")